# Erro: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, version

I had an application and when i update android studio to 3.4.2 version and update `gradle`, I had to force change some library like used `androidx` for `appcomaptibility` and annotations, anyway, after that, the sync of application have not any problem but when i want to run application on device, i get below error. I searched, i add java version to `gradle` and etc but not worked and again i get same error. How can i solve this problem?

> Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

`gradle` of ORMDroid Library:

```
buildscript {
ext.java_version = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility java_version
    targetCompatibility java_version
}
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion  16
}
}

repositories {
google()
}
```

`gradle` of my application:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.java_version = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':ORMDroid')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:29.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.google.android.ginstrumentTestms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:29.1.0'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility java_version
        targetCompatibility java_version
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instancem, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test.test'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 104
        versionName "1.0.4"
    }

}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but in this case you'd just need to update your minSdkVersion in your gradles.

Android O requires a minSdkVersion of 26 so you could update it as so.

```
minSdkVersion 26
```